# Store an array value in jQuery from checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

Hye,

Been trying to do this but still with no solution. I want to store an `Input checkbox` with `array` from a form and `post` the value of the `selected checkbox` using jQuery for delete purpose. I'm unable to get the checkbox value when user make the selection more than 1. May I know the right way to store an array value using jQuery. Below are the codes for html checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="checkBox" value='".$row['staff_id']."'>
```

and this are the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#del").click(function(){
    var del = $("#del").val();
    var checkBox = $("#checkBox:checked").val();
    $.post('admin_cuti/staff-delete.php',
    {
        del : del,
        checkBox : checkBox
    }, function(data){
        $("#result_del").html(data)
       });  
    });
});
```

> update with full codes on my `delete.php`. User can click on multiple
>   checkboxes to delete the data. On my case, it can only delete 1 row.
>   Below are the codes:

```
<?php
require_once('../db_connection/connection-intra.php');
//Delete function
if(isset($_POST['del'])){
    if(empty($_POST['checkBox'])){
        echo "<span style="."color:red"."><br>&nbsp;No record selected</span><p/>";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['checkBox'])){
        $checkbox = $_POST['checkBox'];
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkBox']);$i++){
            $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

            $sql = "DELETE FROM staff WHERE staff_id='$del_id'";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            } 
        } 
    } 
} //end of delete function 
?>
```

Im still in the process of learning for web programming especially in jquery and javascript. Do give me an advice/comment, thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple check boxes?

Comment: instead you can send an array

Comment: Ids should be unique for each element and you are duplicating those.

Comment: Im using multiple checkboxes on a while loop in php & including the ids

Comment: can you provide the delete input?

Comment: Im not infront of my pc now. Will try to add in later. Thanks

Comment: @madalini i updated the codes. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
    $("#del").click(function(){
        var del = $(this).val();
        var checkBox = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
var values = [];
   $.each(checkBox,function(i,v){
       values.push($(v).val());
   });
        $.post('admin_cuti/staff-delete.php',
        {
            del : del,
            checkBox : values
        }, function(data){
            $("#result_del").html(data)
           });  
        });
```

Comment: I tried the codes but it still select 1 row only. If user choose more than 1, it will select the most top value of the choosen checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate IDs for checkbox elements. and id selector only select first element in matched set. you can rather use same class(say `checkBox`) for all checkboxes and then target them using class selector:

```
var checkBox = $(".checkBox:checked").val();
```

you can also use attribute equal sector to target checkboxes based on name attribute:

```
var checkBox = $('[name="checkBox[]"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: i tried to use the class but it only select 1 row only for the value

Comment: @Amran: can you share the fiddle.